# Naming a linear combination with non-negative coefficients, summing to $\leq 1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, convex-optimization

A sum of coefficents multiplying a sequence of terms $\sum_i a_i t_i$ is a [linear combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_combination#Affine,_conical,_and_convex_combinations). We get more specific types of combinations when we make further assumptions. In particular, if we assume $0 \leq a_i$ and $\sum a_i = 1$, we obtain a convex combination / a convex set / a simplex.

In my application, I am lead to consider coefficients that also satisfy the non-negativity assumption $0 \leq a_i$, but instead of summing to one, I require summing to one or less, $\sum a_i \leq 1$.

I'm currently running with an explicit statement in my write-up, but it is a bit lengthy.

> any linear combination of the components such that the coefficients are non-negative and such that the sum of the coefficient is smaller than or equal to $1$ gives rise to ...

"subconvex" sounds fitting and concise:

> any subconvex combination of the components gives rise to ...

But I never heard this expression before, so I'm reluctant to use it. Is there a name for such combinations? If there is no standard terminology for this concept, would there be a more elegant explicit formulation than my current statement? I'm only using this concept once for one small corollary, so it is probably not worth creating a new name just for it and splitting the introduction of the name from the statement I'm making.

Comment: I'd say you've answered your own question correctly with your last sentence.